# Save value of label (JSON) in JS

Tags: javascript, json, npm, label

I know that the question has been asked before but none of the answers have answered it. I'm very confused so would really appreciate some help.

I have a JSON file:

```html
{ 'soapenv:Envelope':
   { '$':
      { 'xmlns:soapenv': 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/',
        'xmlns:xsd': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema',
        'xmlns:xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' },
     'soapenv:Body':
      [ { 'ns1:getTBTransactionsWithFiltersResponse':
           [ { '$':
                { 'soapenv:encodingStyle': 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/',
                  'xmlns:ns1': 'http://TransactionSOAPService/' },
               getTBTransactionsWithFiltersReturn:
                [ { '$':
                     { 'soapenc:arrayType': 'ns2:BeanTBTransaction[1]',
                       'xsi:type': 'soapenc:Array',
                       'xmlns:ns2': 'http://TransactionSOAPService.SOAP.genSrv.tt.slb.com',
                       'xmlns:soapenc': 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/' },
                    getTBTransactionsWithFiltersReturn: [ { '$': { href: '#id0' } } ] } ] } ],
          multiRef:
           [ { '$':
                { id: 'id0',
                  'soapenc:root': '0',
                  'soapenv:encodingStyle': 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/',
                  'xsi:type': 'ns3:BeanTBTransaction',
                  'xmlns:soapenc': 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/',
                  'xmlns:ns3': 'http://TransactionSOAPService.SOAP.genSrv.tt.slb.com' },
               batchId: [ { _: '36', '$': { 'xsi:type': 'xsd:int' } } ],
               currency: [ { _: 'EUR', '$': { 'xsi:type': 'xsd:string' } } ],
               deviceCode: [ { _: '12', '$': { 'xsi:type': 'xsd:string' } } ],
               duration: [ { _: '92', '$': { 'xsi:type': 'xsd:int' } } ],
               errorContext: [ { '$': { 'xsi:type': 'xsd:string', 'xsi:nil': 'true' } } ],
               errorStatus: [ { '$': { 'xsi:type': 'xsd:int', 'xsi:nil': 'true' } } ],
               parkCode: [ { _: '6625', '$': { 'xsi:type': 'xsd:string' } } ],
               payment: [ { '$': { href: '#id1' } } ],
               pndCurrencyTotalPaidAmount: [ { _: '350', '$': { 'xsi:type': 'xsd:int' } } ],
               products:
                [ { '$':
                     { 'soapenc:arrayType': 'ns3:BeanProduct[1]',
                       'xsi:type': 'soapenc:Array' },
                    products: [ { '$': { href: '#id2' } } ] } ],
               transDate:
                [ { _: '2018-08-02T11:38:08.000Z',
                    '$': { 'xsi:type': 'xsd:dateTime' } } ],
               transactionId: [ { _: '36', '$': { 'xsi:type': 'xsd:int' } } ] },
             { '$':
                { id: 'id1',
                  'soapenc:root': '0',
                  'soapenv:encodingStyle': 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/',
                  'xsi:type': 'ns4:BeanPayments',
                  'xmlns:ns4': 'http://TransactionSOAPService.SOAP.genSrv.tt.slb.com',
                  'xmlns:soapenc': 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/' },
               cardsPayments:
                [ { '$':
                     { 'soapenc:arrayType': 'ns4:BeanCardPayment[1]',
                       'xsi:type': 'soapenc:Array' },
                    cardsPayments: [ { '$': { href: '#id3' } } ] } ],
               coinsChannels:
                [ { '$': { 'xsi:type': 'soapenc:Array', 'xsi:nil': 'true' } } ],
               notesChannels:
                [ { '$': { 'xsi:type': 'soapenc:Array', 'xsi:nil': 'true' } } ] },
             { '$':
                { id: 'id2',
                  'soapenc:root': '0',
                  'soapenv:encodingStyle': 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/',
                  'xsi:type': 'ns5:BeanProduct',
                  'xmlns:ns5': 'http://TransactionSOAPService.SOAP.genSrv.tt.slb.com',
                  'xmlns:soapenc': 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/' },
               alphanumId: [ { _: '0D60213205 ', '$': { 'xsi:type': 'xsd:string' } } ],
               amount: [ { _: '350', '$': { 'xsi:type': 'xsd:int' } } ],
               carPN: [ { '$': { 'xsi:type': 'xsd:string', 'xsi:nil': 'true' } } ],
               currency: [ { _: 'EUR', '$': { 'xsi:type': 'xsd:string' } } ],
               custom: [ { '$': { 'xsi:type': 'xsd:string', 'xsi:nil': 'true' } } ],
               depositDeviceCode: [ { '$': { 'xsi:type': 'xsd:string', 'xsi:nil': 'true' } } ],
               depositNumber: [ { '$': { 'xsi:type': 'xsd:int', 'xsi:nil': 'true' } } ],
               durationRequest: [ { '$': { 'xsi:type': 'xsd:int', 'xsi:nil': 'true' } } ],
               endDate:
                [ { '$': { 'xsi:type': 'xsd:dateTime', 'xsi:nil': 'true' } } ],
               extraData: [ { '$': { 'xsi:type': 'xsd:string', 'xsi:nil': 'true' } } ],
               freeDuration: [ { '$': { 'xsi:type': 'xsd:int', 'xsi:nil': 'true' } } ],
               latitude: [ { '$': { 'xsi:type': 'xsd:double', 'xsi:nil': 'true' } } ],
               location: [ { '$': { 'xsi:type': 'xsd:string', 'xsi:nil': 'true' } } ],
               longitude: [ { '$': { 'xsi:type': 'xsd:double', 'xsi:nil': 'true' } } ],
               mobilePhoneOperator: [ { '$': { 'xsi:type': 'xsd:string', 'xsi:nil': 'true' } } ],
               operator: [ { '$': { 'xsi:type': 'xsd:string', 'xsi:nil': 'true' } } ],
               origin: [ { '$': { 'xsi:type': 'xsd:string', 'xsi:nil': 'true' } } ],
               paidDuration: [ { '$': { 'xsi:type': 'xsd:int', 'xsi:nil': 'true' } } ],
               pbsExtensionCode: [ { '$': { 'xsi:type': 'xsd:string', 'xsi:nil': 'true' } } ],
               pbsInitialStartingDate:
                [ { '$': { 'xsi:type': 'xsd:dateTime', 'xsi:nil': 'true' } } ],
               place: [ { '$': { 'xsi:type': 'xsd:string', 'xsi:nil': 'true' } } ],
               productId: [ { '$': { 'xsi:type': 'xsd:int', 'xsi:nil': 'true' } } ],
               productIndex: [ { _: '0', '$': { 'xsi:type': 'xsd:int' } } ],
               productName: [ { '$': { 'xsi:type': 'xsd:string', 'xsi:nil': 'true' } } ],
               startDate:
                [ { '$': { 'xsi:type': 'xsd:dateTime', 'xsi:nil': 'true' } } ],
               status: [ { '$': { 'xsi:type': 'xsd:string', 'xsi:nil': 'true' } } ],
               subscriberId: [ { '$': { 'xsi:type': 'xsd:string', 'xsi:nil': 'true' } } ],
               tariff: [ { '$': { 'xsi:type': 'xsd:string', 'xsi:nil': 'true' } } ],
               type: [ { _: '60', '$': { 'xsi:type': 'xsd:int' } } ],
               user: [ { _: '-1', '$': { 'xsi:type': 'xsd:int' } } ],
               userDurationRequest: [ { '$': { 'xsi:type': 'xsd:int', 'xsi:nil': 'true' } } ] },
             { '$':
                { id: 'id3',
                  'soapenc:root': '0',
                  'soapenv:encodingStyle': 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/',
                  'xsi:type': 'ns6:BeanCardPayment',
                  'xmlns:ns6': 'http://TransactionSOAPService.SOAP.genSrv.tt.slb.com',
                  'xmlns:soapenc': 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/' },
               amountBefore: [ { '$': { 'xsi:type': 'xsd:int', 'xsi:nil': 'true' } } ],
               cadBankId: [ { _: '11', '$': { 'xsi:type': 'xsd:string' } } ],
               carPN: [ { '$': { 'xsi:type': 'xsd:string', 'xsi:nil': 'true' } } ],
               cardSN: [ { '$': { 'xsi:type': 'xsd:string', 'xsi:nil': 'true' } } ],
               cityCode: [ { '$': { 'xsi:type': 'xsd:int', 'xsi:nil': 'true' } } ],
               currency: [ { _: 'EUR', '$': { 'xsi:type': 'xsd:string' } } ],
               mzCode: [ { '$': { 'xsi:type': 'xsd:int', 'xsi:nil': 'true' } } ],
               paidAmount: [ { _: '350', '$': { 'xsi:type': 'xsd:int' } } ],
               type:
                [ { _: 'Pago con tarjeta', '$': { 'xsi:type': 'xsd:string' } } ] } ] } ] } }
```

I want to save all `alphanumId` label into variable.

In this case have one label but there may be more than one.

Have any method to find the value of the label?

Later I would like to save it in a CSV.

Comment: Since there is only one `alphanumId` key in your example it's a little hard to know how to generalize. For example, will it always be in the array `multiRef` (in which case it's a simple matter of using `find`) or could it be anywhere in the hierarchy of the data structure (which would require recursively searching the tree)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I found the solution:

const ast = XmlReader.parseSync(xml);

const x =xmlQuery(ast).find('alphanumId').text();